# Adding img tag to div - and not it's not how to use append()

Tags: jquery, html

I correctly add an img tag with the following code but it only displays as a little box with an X in it on the webpage. To test I added this same img tag right in the webpage. That displays fine. I looked at both img tags in developer tools (PF12), and the tags on the page are the same. What I figure is happening is that in jQuery I'm loading the image tag after all the http requests for content have been scheduled, so I'm getting the tag, but it's too late in the browser's processing to get the source file requested and loaded. I'm trying to load different images on first display of the page (depending on contents of a hidden input field - accessing this and deciding which image is working fine based on a few alerts I've inserted).

Here's the code inserting the image (with the decisioning removed while I work out this problem):

```
$(document).ready (function() {
            $('<img class="rcpt" src="~/Images/MountainCrs_Incline.png" alt="" />').appendTo('div#Logo');
});
```

Here's the inserted img tag which only displays the "unresolved reference" box (copied right from the resulting html):

```
<div id="Logo"><img class="rcpt" alt="" src="~/Images/ChampCrs_Incline.png"></div>
```

Here's the img tag I inserted into the native html to verify the img tag is formatted correctly (this one displays fine):

```
<h3>&nbsp;</h3>
<img class="rcpt" alt="" src="/Images/ChampCrs_Incline.png">
<h3>&nbsp;</h3>
```

If anyone could tell me what's going on and how to fix it I'd much appreciate it. I'm using Visual Studio 11 and IE10 for my testing. Thankx...

Comment: I found my own answer looking over this question. I just noticed the browser removed the "~" from the second img tag (it's present in the source of the page). By removing the "~" from the src attribute on the img tag I'm inserting, I got it to display. I found my answer but I'm a little at a loss as to why this is happening... if anyone would care to add some comments it'd be appreciated....

Answer (score 4):

This is not a valid client url

```
~/Images/MountainCrs_Incline.png
```

That's resolved on server side to a valid url but on client side make no sense. Try replacing that by

```
/Images/MountainCrs_Incline.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a tilde (~) in the src property of the img tag you're inserting with jQuery, but not in the "native html" markup. A tilde is a valid URL character. I'm assuming you're using .NET. Using tildes in URLs the way you are only works server side.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using [ResolveClientUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx):

```
var url = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/MountainCrs_Incline.png") %>';
$('<img class="rcpt" src="' + url + '" alt="" />').appendTo('div#Logo');
```